# Need clarity of Publishing app to playstore and appstore

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Once the mobile application is reviewed by play/App store, How long can we hold the release with out publishing. What will happen if we hold it for long? Documentation is not saying about the same.

Answer (score 0):

in apple connect:
[image: apple release control]

as for google play:
in the publishing overview section you can find  the following:
[image: google console]

which you have to turn on managed publishing for you to be able to release manually to the public after approval.
how long can they stay, I don't think there's a limit I had a build that stayed for about 50 days with no troubles of releasing

Comment: Is there an option for developer to reject the pending release and re-submit for reviewing again?

Comment: yes, you simply dont release it and submit another version

Comment: Second version will also have to go through the review..right?

Comment: Managed publishing is not applicable for initial publishing of app..that is only for updates